# Method paginate does not exist. in laravel after conversion to object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm getting this error for pagination

> Method paginate does not exist.

```
$allTodaysJob = \DB::select(\DB::raw('select * from `new_job` WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())'));

$collection = collect($allTodaysJob)->paginate(10);

return view('common_status',['data'=>$collection]);
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: The error content?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski, this line ====> `$collection = collect($allTodaysJob)->paginate(10);`

Comment: Try: `$allTodaysJob = \DB::select(\DB::raw('select * from 'new_job' WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())'))->get()->toArray();  $collection = $allTodaysJob->paginate(10);`

Answer (score 3):

Paginate works with Eloquent model. Make a model and then If you use model you can do something like this with eloquent:

```
$allTodaysJob = ModelName::where('created_at', DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())->get()->paginate(10);
```

Or if you want to order it by latest:

```
$allTodaysJob = ModelName::where('created_at', DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())->latest()->paginate(10);
```

But if it you want to use raw query you can make a custom pagination method in the current class. first, you make an array, then you pass that array to the paginator method like this code below:

**this is the pagination method:**

```
 protected function paginate($items,$perPage,$request)
    {

        $page = Input::get('page', 1); // Get the current page or default to 1

        $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            array_slice($items, $offset, $perPage, true),
            count($items), $perPage, $page,
            ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]
        );
    }
```

Then you can call the paginate method after you select data from the database, I would recomend to do it with raw method instead of select:

```
$allTodaysJob = \DB::raw('select * from `new_job` WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())')->get();

$allTodaysJob = $this->paginate($allTodaysJob,10,$request);
```

Note that you should pass the Request $request to the index method and then use it in the pagination.Because from that request to specific page through pagination link laravel pagination know which items to select to show in your view.

Hope it would help!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it should go that way:

```
 $collection = collect($allTodaysJob)->get()->toArray()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: i thought it would work but throwing this error `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopvox-replica\app\Http\Controllers\newJobController.php on line 25 and defined

`

Answer (score 1):

`Paginate` works with `eloquent model` or `query builder`, it does not work with `raw sql query`. Make a model of table `new_job` as `NewJob`.

```
$collection = NewJob::where('created_at',date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
$allTodaysJob = \DB::select('select * from `new_job` WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())')->paginate(10);

return view('common_status',['data'=>$allTodaysJob]);
```

Or (I'm using currently)

```
$allTodaysJob = DB::table('new_job')
            ->where('created_at', DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
            ->paginate(10);

return view('common_status',['data'=>$allTodaysJob]);
```

Comment: both the solution is giving `error`  **Second**   as `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

`

Comment: i thought **second sol** would work but throwing above `error` `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

`

Comment: Assign timestamp to variable and add that to where clause

Comment: ya i have tried  this still the same **error**

` $curr = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
    $allTodaysJob = \DB::table('new_job')
            ->where('created_at', $curr)
            ->paginate(10);
      dd($allTodaysJob); `

Comment: Timestamp good to go with [`date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: ya it is working but 5 records has to be returned, it is returning empty result set.  because `DATE(created_at)` is not matching `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Comment: this line `->where('created_at', DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))`

Comment: date("Y-m-d H:i:s") is also return current time stamp. So no issue with that. if your table have only date then add this `date("Y-m-d")`